# Argument 1: cannot convert from

Tags: c#

In Visual Studio I get this error

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Sintra.frmK1s.ProductStockUpdate' to
>   'Sintra.ScannetWebService.ProductUpdate'

on this line

```
int[] updatedResults = Client.Product_Update(updateProduct);
```

I can't figure it out how I sove this. 
Can anyone help?

My code on frmK1s.cs:

```
using System;  
using Sintra.ScannetWebService;

class ProductStockUpdate
 {
     public string Id;
     public int Stock;
  }


ProductStockUpdate updateProduct = new ProductStockUpdate();
updateProduct.Id = 5242;
updateProduct.Stock = 100;


int[] updatedResults = Client.Product_Update(updateProduct);
```

On Sintra.ScannetWebService

```
public int[] Product_Update(Sintra.ScannetWebService.ProductUpdate ProductData) {
            Sintra.ScannetWebService.Product_UpdateRequest inValue = new Sintra.ScannetWebService.Product_UpdateRequest();
            inValue.ProductData = ProductData;
            Sintra.ScannetWebService.Product_UpdateResponse retVal = ((Sintra.ScannetWebService.WebServicePort)(this)).Product_Update(inValue);
            return retVal.Product_UpdateResult;
        }
```

Comment: Error is pretty self-descriptive - you are not passing value which your method expects to get

Comment: If you go to an Australian supermarket and try and pay with US Dollars, what happens? The cashier says "we don't take that". That is what the compiler is telling you.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the web service:

```
public int[] Product_Update(Sintra.ScannetWebService.ProductUpdate ProductData) {
            Sintra.ScannetWebService.Product_UpdateRequest inValue = new Sintra.ScannetWebService.Product_UpdateRequest();
            inValue.ProductData = ProductData;
            Sintra.ScannetWebService.Product_UpdateResponse retVal = ((Sintra.ScannetWebService.WebServicePort)(this)).Product_Update(inValue);
            return retVal.Product_UpdateResult;
        }
```

**The method is expecting** `Sintra.ScannetWebService.ProductUpdate` **object type**

**You are passing** `ProductStockUpdate` **object type**:

```
int[] updatedResults = Client.Product_Update(updateProduct);
class ProductStockUpdate
 {
     public string Id;
     public int Stock;
  }
```

*Please pass the correct object to the given method:* `Sintra.ScannetWebService.ProductUpdate` *object type*:

`Sintra.ScannetWebService.ProductUpdate = new Sintra.ScannetWebService.ProductUpdate();`

Comment: You might want to specify that he need his web service class to be a data contract so the web reference see the class on the client side

Comment: That is in case of a WCF service, if it is a WebService then there is no need

Comment: You are right. He should specify the technology he is using.